# What are the newest alternative to all-in-one game engines?

Tags: c++, java

I have been seaching a while for recent alternative to engines like unity or unreal, however, I haven't found one actively maintained that meet my needs.

For instance, I tried irrlicht with maps editors such as 3D world studio or irrEdit, but those didn't have any big feature update since 2010.

That is why I'm looking for new alternatives, here are my constrains :
- Language : C, C++ or JAVA
- Able to render 2D sprites in 3D world ( like the battles of agarest)
- Native Bumpmap support
- Lightweight
- Run both on linux and windows
- Compatible with free or low-cost map editors
- Able to do Borderless fullscreen

Comment: UE4 is a framework which has all the tools people generally need. But it's not like Unity where it's an all in one, where you HAVE to use the editor provided to make a game. You can use UE4 standalone without the provided editor.

Comment: There is cryengine, torque3D, Source, ID Tech 3-4, rolling your own with SDL/clanlib/Allegro/SFML, un fact there are a lot, but questions like that are nlt parte of this site. gameDev.net might be more helpful